# Undefined Variable in my widget

Tags: widgets

I'm trying to get my head around writing custom widgets with options. I've been following a few tutorials and have been trying to understand as I go.

I've got a widget that works perfectly in the Widgets manager, but on the front end I get `Undefined variable: image_path`. I can't track down what I've done wrong and would definitely appreciate another set of eyes.

Widget code:

```
/* Image Link Widget
===================================================== */
class ImageLinkWidget extends WP_Widget {

  function ImageLinkWidget() {
    $widget_ops = array(
      'classname' => 'google-map-widget nopadding',
      'description' => 'An image that links somewhere'
    );
    $this->WP_Widget('ImageLinkWidget', 'Image + Link', $widget_ops);
  }

  function form($instance) {
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '', 'image_path' => 'default' ) );
    $title = $instance['title'];
    $image_path = $instance['image_path']
    ?>
      <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">
          Title: 
          <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" />
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('image_path'); ?>">
          Image Path (include http://): 
          <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('image_path'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('image_path'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($image_path); ?>" />
        </label>
      </p>
    <?php
  }

  function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
    $instance['image_path'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['image_path'] );
    return $instance;
  }

  function widget($args, $instance) {
    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

    echo $before_widget;
    $title = empty($instance['title']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);

    if (!empty($title))
      echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

    // Show image plus link
    //echo '<a href="' . $link . '" target="' . $target . '">';
      //echo '<img src="' . $image_path . '" alt="' . $alt_text . '">';
      echo $image_path;
    //echo '</a>';

    echo $after_widget;
  }

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("ImageLinkWidget");') );
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$instance['image_path']`, or extract `$instance` (I prefer the former).